# CSS font-variant-numeric slashed zero not working

Tags: html, css

I try to make difference between zero and letter 'O' in a sensitive information by adding the following css property `font-variant-numeric:slashed-zero` but it doesn't work.
i followed this turorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric, but no result.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/akrima/gumkf28o/1/) you can find out what i did and also the result.

Have you any idea or alternative to solve this issue ?

Comment: Try using a different `font-family` https://nimb.ws/aeWmVL

Comment: This feature works only with OpenType fonts!

Comment: @AdamP. should i import something to work with OpenType fonts ?

Comment: @m4n0 it's also not working on my end :/

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, you'll need to use OpenType fonts. In the example below I used the `@font-face` settings from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric#setting_ordinal_numeric_forms) and changed the Google Fonts CDN to jsDelvr CDN via the `<link>` tag. I found the OpenType css file by googling: "SourceSansPro-Regular.otf cdn".

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b86qa3rz/)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  src: url("SourceSansPro-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

.value3 {
  font-variant-numeric: slashed-zero;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                    initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/source-sans-pro@3.6.0/source-sans-pro.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <span>Slashes-zero: </span>
    <span class="value3">0Oo1lL</span>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example has spaces in the Google Fonts URL, which are incorrect. The URL should read `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;1,400&display=swap`. Unfortunately, Google Fonts does not seem to support this feature, presumably because it offers woff2 files instead of OTF.

https://practice.typekit.com/lesson/caring-about-opentype-features/ has some nice working examples. If you open one of them in CodePen, and add `font-variant-numeric: slashed-zero;` to the relevant section (e.g. `.since` in the first example, and `td` in the last example), you'll see the behavior you're looking for. These examples work using [Adobe TypeKit](https://fonts.adobe.com/). Here's a working example:

```css
body {
            font-family: "source-sans-pro";
}
.slashed {
            font-variant-numeric: slashed-zero;
}
```

```html
<script src="//use.typekit.net/ihq4gbu.js"></script><script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<p>
    <span>Slashed zero: </span>
    <span class="slashed">0Oo1lL</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span>Unslashed zero: </span>
    <span class="unslashed">0Oo1lL</span>
</p>
```